# OpenVPN TAP interface security

Tags: openvpn, bridge

**Background:** I am very naive about how bridging works. I wanted to know bridging interfaces exposes devices on both ends of the bridge to communicate?

**Question:**

- How secure is the openvpn tap interface?
- Since it is a bridge interface will people be able to see traffic
  from a dlna server I have on my home network?
- What about regular interface bridging. If I were to bridge two
  interfaces on a machine, can machines on both ends see each other?

Answer (score 0):

[Bridging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)) works like a filter. It is up to your bridging configuration to decide which packets get through to the network. If you are concerned about the visibility of particular hosts, you can [use nmap to scan your network](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/how-to-find-live-hosts-on-my-network) from both sides of the bridge and confirm what hosts you see from either side.